# LINQ to SQL Inheritance InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, linq, orm

Trying to get my head around LINQ and inheritance mapping I get the exception in DBContext.cs when the connectionstring line is executed:

`Could not retrieve Table for inheritance subtype 'Movie, try Table of 'Media' instead`

**DBContext.cs**

```
[Database]
public class DBContext : DataContext
{
    public DBContext() : base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString){ }

    public Table<Member> members;
    public Table<Media> media;
    public Table<Movie> movies;
    public Table<Game> games;
    public Table<Track> tracks;
    public Table<Album> albums;
  //  public Table<Loaned> loaned;
}
```

**Media.cs**

```
[Table(Name="media")]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = 1, Type = typeof(Movie), IsDefault=true)]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = 2, Type = typeof(Game))]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = 3, Type = typeof(Album))]
[InheritanceMapping(Code = 4, Type = typeof(Track))]
public class Media
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public string itemId;

    [Column]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string price { get; set; }

    [Column(IsDiscriminator=true)]
    public int itemType { get; set; }
}
```

**Movie.cs**

```
public class Movie : Media
{
    [Column]
    public int year { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code calling it all:

```
    public static void GetAll()
    {
        using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Media> media = from m in db.media select m;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I'm missing some pesky mapping attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I didn't pay attention to LINQ's `single table inheritance`. I removed all but:

```
public Table<Member> members;
public Table<Media> media;
```

Now it works. I had each media item in its own table, which is not supported.